# Compare two List<Control> before/after based on propertie

Tags: c#, list, compare

Let's say we have 4 buttons on a form; Every 5 seconds those buttons' background color changes randomly (but It can also stay the same)
How could I get only the buttons that have changed their background out ?

```
List<Button> oldList;
        oldList = new List<Button>();
        foreach (Button item in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            //First we catch all the buttons' instances at for e.g 12:00
            oldList.Add(item);
        }

        buttonsChangeColor(); //Five seconds later some buttons change their bg color

        List<Button> newList = new List<Button>();
        foreach (Button item in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            //2nd we catch all the buttons' instances at for e.g 12:05 after some of theme changed color
            newList.Add(item);
        }

        //HOW CAN I COMPARE THESE 2 LISTS BASED ON THE BACKGROUNDCOLOR ? If it has changed or not
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the instances of the buttons are the same in `oldList` and `newList`, you need to remember the old background colors to compare them with the new ones.

The following should work:

```
var oldList = Controls.OfType<Button>().ToDictionary(btn => btn, btn => btn.BackColor);
buttonsChangeColor();
var changedBackgrounds = Controls.OfType<Button>()
    .Where(btn => oldList[btn] != btn.BackColor).ToList();
```

Comment: @Niiw Just in case you don't know: You can also upvote an answer if it helped.  ;-)

Comment: @Niiw You accepted my answer but you can click on the up arrow too where it says "This answer is useful". That click grants extra reputation and it would be absolutely awesome if you would do that if my answer indeed was useful.  :-)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for that, I tryed though :-p

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
var changed = oldList.Zip(newList, (old, new) => new { Old = old, New = new })
                     .Where(old.BackColor != new.BackColor);
```

`Enumerable.Zip` pairs two collections element by element. If you just modified colors, the order shouldn't change - so it would be enough.

Comment: You may want to further select the `New` post `Where`, for actual List with changes